# calling outer class overridden method

Tags: java, this, inner-classes

I have two classes. The outer class `Mainannony` and an annonymous inner class which overrides Outer class `Mainannony` method `display()` but using outerclass class reference.

```
class Mainannony {
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("java annonymous");
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Mainannony a1=new Mainannony(){
            public void display(){
                System.out.println("this is the annonymous class");
            }   
        };
        a1.display();
    }   
}
```

Calling inner method works. But, when I tried to call outer class method using `outerclass.this.method()`, it shows the error `non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`.

Comment: Yup, `main` is `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `display()` method you are creating *overrides* the default implementation; you are creating an anonymous *subclass* of `Mainannony`. So if you wanted to call the default implementation from within the anonymous class, you'd use `super.display()`. Outside the anonymous class, like in the `main()` method, it is not possible with just a reference to the anonymous instance `a1`.